# Google charged me $5000 in a month for using Google Place API

Tags: flutter, vue.js, google-places-api

My project is under development, `Vuejs` and `Flutter` in the frontend and `Laravel` is in the backend.
I am using `Google place autocomplete API` in this project, I made a big mistake due to not having enough knowledge of using `google apiz`.

After trial finished google charged $5000.

My mistakes were 2 things;
**Requesting unnecessary data** and **not providing sessionToken**

I am posting my edited codes here if anyone can check it please, I'm afraid to make mistake again.

vuejs code

```
mounted() {
    this.$refs.focusable.focus();
    let $vm = this;
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      document.getElementById("autocomplete"),
      {
        componentRestrictions: { country: "ca" },
        fields: ["address_components", "formatted_address", "geometry"],
        types: ["address"],
        bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
          new google.maps.LatLng(49.246292, -123.116226)
        ),
        //strictbounds: true,
      }
    );

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, "place_changed", function () {
      var data = autocomplete.getPlace();
      let latlng = {
        lat: data.geometry.location.lat(),
        lng: data.geometry.location.lng(),
      };
      data.address_components.forEach((component) => {
        if (component.types.indexOf("administrative_area_level_1") > -1) {
          if ($vm.checkState(component.short_name)) {
            $vm.validAddress(data, latlng);
          } else {
            $vm.invalidAddress(data);
          }
        }
      });
    });
  },
```

According to google docs [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#session_tokens) I don't need to provide `sessionToken` for `Autocomplete widget`. and I think my code is correct here.

and this is my Flutter code

```
 TextFormField(
          autofocus: true,
          controller: _addressController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Postal code'),
          onChanged: (val) {
            final sessionToken = Uuid.v4();
            findPlace(val, sessionToken);
          },
        ),


//get a place
  void findPlace(String placeName, String sessionToken) async {
    if (placeName.length > 1) {
      String autoComplete =
          "$googleApi?input=$placeName&types=address&components=country:ca&key=$mapKey&sessiontoken=$sessionToken";
      var res = await http.get(Uri.parse(autoComplete));
      Map data = jsonDecode(res.body);
      var predictions = data['predictions'];
      var placesList = (predictions as List)
          .map((e) => PlacePredictions.fromJson(e))
          .toList();

      setState(() {
        sToken = sessionToken;
        placePredictionList = placesList;
      });
    }
  }

// get place details using place_id
  addressDetails(placeId, sessionToken) async {
    String fields = 'address_component,formatted_address,geometry';
    String placeDetailsUrl =
        "$googleApiDetails?place_id=$placeId&fields=$fields&key=$mapKey&sessiontoken=$sessionToken";
    var res = await http.get(Uri.parse(placeDetailsUrl));
    Map data = jsonDecode(res.body);
}
```

In the above Flutter code there is a confusion for me is this `sessiontoken` or `sessionToken` I don't know how to check it and there is no any information in the `Google docs`.

Help really appreciated.

Comment: First, reach out to Google, explain that it was a mistake and you've deactivated the app, and request they cancel the charge. Chances are they will be willing to do so as a one-off courtesy.

Comment: I contacted google due to that, I want to make sure not doing any mistake in my code.

Comment: Were you able to clear this up? I'm going through the same issue and trying to get a hold of support!

Comment: @Simone my project owner contacted Google and the amount refunded, because our apps are in testing mode.

Answer (score 1):

Can't post as a comment as I don't have the required rep.

But you can cap your API usage so things like these won't happen.
Read more here: https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage

> 1. In the Google Cloud console, go to the APIs & Services Dashboard page.
> 2. From the projects list, select a project or create a new one.
> 3. Click the name of the API you're interested in.
> 4. Click Quotas. If the Quotas tab is not present in the tab nav, it means the API you've selected doesn't have quotas defined.
> 5. To find the quota you want to cap, enter the appropriate properties and values in the filter_list Filter field. For example, to find the Subnetworks quota, enter Quota:Subnetworks.
> 6. Click the checkbox next to the quota you want to cap, and then click create EDIT QUOTAS.
> 7. Complete the quota change form, including the new limit that you want to set.
> 8. Click SUBMIT REQUEST.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, any idea about sessionToken?